# Odd results when parsing array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I'm building a bash script that gets information from GeekTool and parses the results. The so far the script looks like this:

```
1  #!/bin/bash
2  
3  clear
4  
5  geeklets=`osascript <<TEXT
6      Tell Application "GeekTool Helper"
7          geeklets
8      End Tell
9  TEXT`
10 
11 IFS="," read -a geekletArray <<< "$geeklets"
12 
13 echo "First Element in Array:"
14 echo ${geekletArray[0]}
15 
16 echo ""
17 
18 echo "All Array Elements:"
19 for element in ${geekletArray[@]}
20 do
21     echo $element
22 done
```

At line 14 I echo out the first element of the array which returns:

```
shell geeklet id 49610161-0A3C-49C6-9626-694370DE3101
```

but on the first iteration of the loop that steps through the array (line 21), the first element array is returned like this:

```
shell
geeklet
id
49610161-0A3C-49C6-9626-694370DE3101
```

In the loop the elements are returned in a newline delimited list.

Why is there a difference? Also, if I wanted to grab just the id value of the array (e.g. `49610161-0A3C-49C6-9626-694370DE3101`), how would I go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: `for element in "${array[@]}"` -- the double quotes are mandatory.

Comment: ...see also http://shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting of arrays can be confusing.  You can sidestep the issue completely by iterating over the array indices instead.

There are lots of ways to pull out the id value from the resulting string.  I am assuming it will always be the last part of a space-delimited string.  As such, I am using a [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to effectively remove all occurrences of the [pattern `*`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)

```
for index in ${!geekletArray[@]}
do
    echo "${geekletArray[$index]}"       # entire element
    echo "${geekletArray[$index]##* }"   # id value only
done
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for element in "${geekletArray[@]}"
do
   echo "$element"
done
```

Judicious use of quotes will protect you from undesired word splitting.